# Sort of an OR operation on two strings in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have two strings:

```
StringA = "SushantSingh"
StringB = "SinghRajput"
```

Desired resultant string is:

```
result = "SushantSinghRajput"
```

How to get the result string using some operations in python from StringA and StringB? A good/clean way. Basically sort of an OR Operation.

My attempt for others to view:

```
import difflib
StringA = "SushantSingh"
StringB = "SinghRajput"
res = ""
res_S = ""
res = [li[2] for li in difflib.ndiff(StringA,StringB)]
for ele in res:
    res_S+=ele
print(res_S)
```

Out: 'SushantSinghRajput'

but I seek even less lines answer.
more short version is:

```
import difflib
StringA = "SushantSingh"
StringB = "SinghRajput"
res = ''.join([li[2] for li in difflib.ndiff(StringA,StringB)])
print(res)
```

any other better way without using difflib ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do that would be using startsWith and iterating over one string:

```
StringA = "SushantSingh"
StringB = "SinghRajput"

merged = ""

for index in range(len(StringA)):
    if StringB.startswith(StringA[index:]):
        merged = StringA[:index] + StringB
        break
else:
    merged = StringA + StringB

print(merged)
```

But it is obviously not a one liner, if this was your requirement ...

Answer (score 0):

@Sami Tahri answer is good but I think it is better if you start from the end of  of **StringA** is more efficient.

```
StringA = "SushantSingh"
StringB = "SinghRajput"

merged = ""
for i in range(len(StringA)-1, -1, -1):
    if StringB.startswith(StringA[i:]):
        merged = StringA[:i]+StringB
        break
else:
    merged = StringA+StringB
print(merged)
```

Comment: Imho this should have been a comment on @SamiTahri's answer, not a stand-alone answer?

Comment: ok sorry i am new